# Are the contents of the overheard conversation at the beginning of the game ever resolved?

Tags: firewatch

In the early parts of *Firewatch*, Delilah receives a call from someone else. She tells you to hold on, but conspicuously leaves your frequency open. You can then overhear her side of the conversation she's having:

> - Heyo. I don't think so. Why, have you?
> - *[annoyed]* Okay, good.
> - No, I don't think he has any idea.
> - I'm absolutely sure.
> - Would you?
> - Alright. I'll let you know if anything changes in that regard.

If you immediately call her out on it, she gets annoyed and stops talking to you. Later on, when things start to get spooky, you can mention the conversation again as an example of the lines being bugged. Here, she brushes off your concern saying she just left the line open.

In my play through, that seemed to be the extent of that plot thread. Is there additional dialogue that I may have missed that resolves who Delilah was talking to, and why she seems to imply you're in the dark about something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't supposed to mean anything, or if anything, it was there to add a bit of paranoia to the relationship between you and Delilah (a recurring theme in the game).

IGN did a [spoiler podcast with the developers of the game](http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/02/12/firewatch-secrets-spoilers-and-behind-the-scenes-with-campo-santo) and brought it up (at 34:50):

> **Marty Sliva (IGN):** ...like the way you react to Delilah: whether you call her out on her weirdo conversation with someone else. Which also, I want to talk about: what was the deal with that?
>
> **Sean Vanaman (Campo Santo):** Yeah, people freak. She was just talking to someone else.
>
> **Marty:** Why was she talking about me?
>
> **Sean:** She wasn't talking about you.
>
> **Jake Rodkin (Campo Santo):** You just assume that if anyone's talking it's about you?
>
> **Sean:** You go back and listen to it, she just wasn't talking about you.
>
> **Mitch Dyer (IGN):** Yeah, the second time through it's very clear. She's having a completely separate conversation. And if you ask her about it and be like "hey, what's up?" "Dude, I'm in the middle of something: please leave me alone. I'm just talking to someone. What are you paranoid about?"
>
> **Sean:** It's funny, if I had to do like a director's cut version of the game right now, I would probably put in a third choice there, where you can say, "hey, uhm, I kinda heard you talking to someone. I'm sure it was nothing." You know, just like, the more pokey one? And she'd be like "oh yeah that was just this dude in another lookout tower and we're just dealing with this bureaucratic mess and I don't know what this guy is doing but it's annoying. Anyway, you ever have any coworkers?" And you'd just be like "oh okay, yeah, that's life."

Comment: Well that's disappointing.

Comment: I don't think it's disappointing. It fits very well into the theme of having a kinda weird experience that ultimately turns out to be very mundane. I love the vibe of that game and I don't understand how people feel that the ending is anticlimactic or anything